# Como acessar atributos de um JSON que foi convertido com caracteres especiais?

Tags: c#, json, xml, conversão-de-tipo

Eu estou consumindo a API de [tradução da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstarts/csharp), eles trabalham com o retorno em `XML`(Pois é, a MICROSOFT retorna XML nas suas API'S), eu consegui executar tudo certinho, porém como odeio trabalhar com XML eu decidi converter de XML para JSON, com a biblioteca [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm), a resposta da tradução em XML é:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Mechanical</string>
```

Quando eu converto para JSON através do Json.NET:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(response.Content);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
Debug.WriteLine(json);
```

Eu recebo isso:

```
{"string":{"@xmlns":"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/","#text":"mechanical"}}
```

Se eu tento acessar `string.#text` eu recebo um erro no navegador:

> SyntaxError: illegal character

Como acessar `#text` se o conversor de formato está adicionando caracteres especiais no nome dos atributos? Eu percebi que isso ocorre no [próprio exemplo](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm) do Json.NET

Comment: Isso é um padrão xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/ ? Sempre vem isso na resposta?

Comment: @perozzo yes, essa resposta é padrão da API

Comment: @perozzo já consegui ;)

Comment: Boa! Ia sugerir para remover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" do response.Content antes de converter, mas já que conseguiu da maneira certa, melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando há caracteres especiais no nome do atributo, basta chama-lo com conchetes([]).

```
{"string":{"@xmlns":"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/","#text":"mechanical"}}
```

Acesse `#text` assim:

```
console.log(string["#text"]); //mechanical
```